# Rust tonic tonic::include_proto file path from one module to another module in tonic build

Tags: rust, tonic, rust-tonic

I am implementing gRPC client and server using  [Tonic](https://docs.rs/tonic/latest/tonic/). I have two modules each module depending on another module proto file. I am facing an issue when I try to provide the path of the proto file in tonic build. Below is my folder structure and code for the tonic build.

```
   -organization
     -src
       -client
         -mod.rs
       -service
       -cargo.toml
   -Employee
     -src
       -service
       -proto
         -proto_file
       -cargo.toml
```

```
pub mod Employee_info {
    tonic::include_proto!("{path}/employee_info.proto"); //this is organisation `mod file`. i want to pass the proto file path of employee folder->proto->proto file.
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it follows the usage described in the [docs](https://docs.rs/tonic/latest/tonic/macro.include_proto.html) or [tutorial](https://github.com/hyperium/tonic/blob/master/examples/helloworld-tutorial.md). The `build.rs` file should be compiling the *".proto"* files and then `include_proto!` should reference them by *proto package name*.

Answer (score 1):

You `employee_info.proto` should be compiled into rust file `employee_info.rs`.

Your `build.rs` file should look sth like this:

```
fn main() {
    let proto_file = "./src/proto/employee_info.proto";
    tonic_build::configure()
        .build_server(true)
        .out_dir("./src")
        .compile(&[proto_file], &["."])
        .unwrap_or_else(|e| panic!("protobuf compile error: {}", e));
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed={}", proto_file);
}
```

After `cargo build`, expect to see the following file being generated: `src/employee_info.rs`.

Then you just need include this in your code as usual:

```
mod employee_info {
    include!("employee_info.rs");
}
```

As explained in https://docs.rs/tonic/latest/tonic/macro.include_proto.html, you can only include the package via `tonic::include_proto` when output directory has been unmodified.